# Ошибка сборки релизного apk-файла в android проекте Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt

Здравствуйте, cразу скажу что стоит: Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, Qt 5.7.0 for Android, Qt Creator 4.1.0, NDK r10e, SDK Tools 25.2.3, SDK Platform-, Build-tools 25.0.1, вся ветка "Extras" в SDK Manager, Android API 17, Java 8 (111),  Gradle 2.14.1, GCC 4.9.

Проект пустышка, добавил только пару элементов на форму (.ui). Релизный ключ создавал как из терминала (keytool), так и в Qt Creator. Дебаг версия компилируется и собирается, на устройстве запускается и работает корректно. А вот релизная только компилируется, не собирается.

Сама ошибка:

```
/home/xessao/Qt/5.7/android_armv7/src/android/java/res/values/strings.xml:7: Error: "unsupported_android_version" is not translated in "de" (German), "el" (Greek), "es" (Spanish), "et" (Estonian), "fa" (Persian), "fr" (French), "id" (Indonesian), "it" (Italian), "ja" (Japanese), "ms" (Malay), "nb" (Norwegian Bokmål), "nl" (Dutch), "pl" (Polish), "pt-BR" (Portuguese: Brazil), "rs", "ru" (Russian), "zh-CN" (Chinese: China), "zh-TW" (Chinese: Taiwan) [MissingTranslation]
    <string name="unsupported_android_version">Unsupported Android version.</string>
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

   Explanation for issues of type "MissingTranslation":
   If an application has more than one locale, then all the strings declared
   in one language should also be translated in all other languages.

   If the string should not be translated, you can add the attribute
   translatable="false" on the <string> element, or you can define all your
   non-translatable strings in a resource file called donottranslate.xml. Or,
   you can ignore the issue with a tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"
   attribute.

   By default this detector allows regions of a language to just provide a
   subset of the strings and fall back to the standard language strings. You
   can require all regions to provide a full translation by setting the
   environment variable ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS.

   You can tell lint (and other tools) which language is the default language
   in your res/values/ folder by specifying tools:locale="languageCode" for
   the root <resources> element in your resource file. (The tools prefix
   refers to the namespace declaration http://schemas.android.com/tools.)

1 errors, 0 warnings

Процесс «/home/xessao/Qt/5.7/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt» завершился с кодом 15.
```

Пробовал в файл `build.gradle` добавлять `lintOptions { disable 'MissingTranslation' abortOnError false }`, пропадала сама ошибка, но процесс `androiddeployqt` завершался с кодом `15`.

Какие будут предложения по решению этой проблемы?

Comment: Неужели никто не может помочь?

Comment: Скажите, Вам удалось решить эту проблему?

Comment: @pier_nasos, нет, к сожалению.

Comment: только некоторые сочетания версий Qt, SDK и NDK нормально работают,  надо в описании для конкретной Qt версии читать, какой SDK и NDK для неё рекомендуются

Answer (score 1):

У меня была такая же проблема.
Это ругается лингвист. Он не может быть запущен.
Причина в версии NDK. У меня стояла x86_64.

Ожидался путь: `<ndk root>\prebuilt\windows\`, а в наличии `<ndk root>\prebuilt\windows-x86_64`. После того как я скачал\установил\настроил x86 версию NDK и установил переменную среды `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` - компиляция стала успешной.